# C++ iterator much slower than indexing?

Tags: c++

I have a `O(N^2)` program and I notice the huge difference between using iterator and index, I paste the code and data here:

code:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream> 
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std; 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    ifstream ifile("csv.csv"); 
    string s; 

    vector<long> vec_frd;
    vector<long> vec_real_frd;

    while (getline(ifile, s)){
        string s2 = s.substr(0, s.find(','));
        vec_frd.push_back(stol(s.substr(0, s.find(',')))); 
    }    
    long real_frd;

    // using iterator 
    vector<long>::iterator it1, it2;
    for (it1=vec_frd.begin(); it1<vec_frd.end(); it1++){
        if (*it1 == -1){
            vec_real_frd.push_back(-1);
            continue; 
        }
        real_frd = *it1; 
        for (it2=it1; it2<it1+*it1 && it2<vec_frd.end(); it2++){
            if (*it2 == -1)
                real_frd --;
        }
        vec_real_frd.push_back(real_frd);
    }

    // using index 
    // for (unsigned int i=0; i<vec_frd.size(); i++){
    //     if (vec_frd[i] == -1){
    //         vec_real_frd.push_back(-1);
    //         continue; 
    //     }
    //     real_frd = vec_frd[i]; 
    //     for (unsigned int j=i; j<i+vec_frd[i] && j<vec_frd.size(); j++){
    //         if (vec_frd[j] == -1)
    //             real_frd --;
    //     }
    //     vec_real_frd.push_back(real_frd);
    // }        

    ifile.close();
    return 1; 
}
```

data: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/c2c7txhu24xy06r/csv.csv?dl=0

if we use iterator, on my machine it takes almost 30s, if we use index instead, it takes 5s, I am new to C++, is that kind of performance difference normal? Or am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: Compiler optimization on?

Comment: 1. C and C++ are different languages. 2. Code needs to be in the question not as external links.

Comment: Why spamming with unrelated language tags? This is no valid C Code.

Comment: yes, o2 added @XinHuang

Comment: sorry, remove the wrong tag @Gerhardh

Comment: sorry, wrong tag removed and code added @kaylum

Comment: why am I down voted?

Comment: `i+j<vec_frd.size()`: This does not look like it's doing the same comparison as `it2<vec_frd.end()`. Also, there's the fact that you cannot increment an iterator beyond the one-past-the-end iterator.

Comment: I agree with @NicolBolas, I guess you want
for (unsigned int j=i; j<i+vec_frd[i] && j<vec_frd.size(); j++){
instead of
for (unsigned int j=i; j<i+vec_frd[i] && i+j<vec_frd.size(); j++){

Comment: yes, you are right, just fix the bug, but still the running time for index is much shorter (6.5s now). @NicolBolas

Comment: If you're using visual studio, have it build a "release" build. Then go find that executable outside of visual studio, and run it separately. You should get the fairest comparison that way.

Comment: @1a1a11a Did you make the time measurement with non-debug code (or even optimized like proposed by Xin Huang)? I realized that results with debug code are very questionable in VC++. The iterator impl. may do something like range-checking if `_DEBUG` is defined.

Comment: @MooingDuck I am testing on Ubuntu 16 with g++ 5.40, and not familiar with VS.

Comment: @Scheff what is the corresponding optimizations for g++ on Ubuntu?

Comment: @1a1a11a I don't know but I know how knows: please, type in your shell `man g++`.

Comment: Have you seen the source code for iterators? *Awful!* They work but for anything beyond minimal functionality, write your own or use alternative methods.

Comment: @1a1a11a: Corresponding for G++ is to simply pass the -O3 flag when compiling.

Comment: Thank you! I passed -o3, which should be uppercase. @MooingDuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question - no, this behavior is most definetly not normal for the optimized code.
I could not reproduce it with gcc or MSVC. Your best bet I think is to carefully check your compiler options.

On a side note, I believe you can speed this task up quite a bit with some algorithm tweaking. Even asymptotically I'm pretty sure you can go from `O(N^2)` to `O(N)` by precomputing a couple of counters.

Comment: here is the cflag I used `-c -o3 -Wall -std=c++11`, any suggestion?

Comment: it seems I have figured out a `O(N)` algorithm. :)

Comment: @1a1a11a I tried these flags and got the same result again, really weird.  
with `std::partial_sum` and `std::transform` you can get it done pretty much without any explicit indexes or iterators :D

Comment: still not familiar with C++, but trying to learn, thank you for the suggestion about `std::partial_sum` and `std::transform`, what is your gcc version? I tried both g++ 5.4 and clang 3.80, similar results, except clang++ is slightly faster than g++, CPU i7-6700.

Comment: @1a1a11a not sure if this is typo or wrong cflag, but o should be capital for optimization

Comment: @1a1a11a Your compiler flags are wrong.  You are using -o (lowercase) instead of -O (uppercase).  -o3 will output to a file called "3".  -O3 will turned on optimization level 3.  I've tried your code on G++ 4.8.2 and Visual Studio 2013 and there is very little difference between index and iterator versions.

Comment: @PetarPetrovic thank you for pointing out, I used lowercase, that's the reason.

Comment: @Alan Yes, I changed to uppercase, and it is super fast now. Thank you!

Comment: @1a1a11a now you can dive into some SSE and speed it up even more, especially if you have access to AVX2 (which i7-6700 does indeed have) :D  
  To be honest though your major bottleneck by now is reading the .csv, so nevermind

Comment: @Ap31 Thank you for the nice suggestions, the data posted is just sample data, real data is much much larger than that and the complete algorithm is still O(N2), can't be optimized like the simplified one I posted. So your suggestions sounds very attractive, I know nothing about architecture, but I am very interested to learn that, can you point me to some directions where I can find materials about SSE and AVX2? Really appreciated it.